# Draw lines on top of another android application

Tags: android

Is it possible to draw a line on top of other app?

For example, there is an app that shows a map, and I want to draw a line on top of that other application, for example a route from A to B.

I added the permission

> android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW

And added code to show the view on top of other app.

```
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final WindowManager.LayoutParams param=new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    param.flags=WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE;
    final View view=findViewById(R.id.my_floating_view);
    final ViewGroup parent=(ViewGroup)view.getParent();
    if(parent!=null)
      parent.removeView(view);
    param.format=PixelFormat.RGBA_8888;
    param.type=WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT;
    param.gravity=Gravity.CENTER;
    param.width=parent!=null?LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT:view.getLayoutParams().width;
    param.height=parent!=null?LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT:view.getLayoutParams().height;
    final WindowManager wmgr=(WindowManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    wmgr.addView(view,param);
}
```

My problem is that when i open my app I see the entire activity, and I want the activity to be hidden and to see only the view the is on top of another application.
i.e. in my example of the map application, I want to see the map and on top of it to see the lines that I draw. I don't want to see the name of my application,etc.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it was [explained here](http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/) how Facebook made their Chathead app float above other apps and that you have to run it as a service. I followed an [example](https://github.com/EatHeat/FloatingExample) that makes an image icon float above everything else. Here is the code from the example. It is not an exact answer to what you want, but it should help, and you can tweak the code to what you need to have done. You started off in the right direction and i hope this will help narrow that absolute direction you need.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.floatingicon;

import com.example.floatingicon.R;
import com.example.floatingicon.MainService;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle){
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Bundle bund = getIntent().getExtras();

        if(bund != null && bun.getString("LAUNCH").equals("YES")){
            startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainService.class));
        }

        Button start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
        start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainService.class));
            }
        });

        Button stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
        stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainService.class));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        Bundle bund = getIntent().getExtras();

        if(bund != null && bund.getString("LAUNCH").equals("YES")){
            startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainService.class));
        }
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

**MainService.java**

```
package com.example.floatingicon;

import com.example.floatingicon.R;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainService extends Service {

    private WindowManager windowManager;
    private ImageView floatIcon;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        floatIcon = new ImageView(this);

        floatIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.floating);

        final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 100;

        windowManager.addView(floatIcon, params);

        try {
            floatIcon.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                private WindowManager.LayoutParams paramsF = params;
                private int initialX;
                private int initialY;
                private float initialTouchX;
                private float initialTouchY;

                @Override 
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        // Get current time in nano seconds.
                        initialX = paramsF.x;
                        initialY = paramsF.y;
                        initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                        initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        paramsF.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                        paramsF.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                        windowManager.updateViewLayout(floatIcon, paramsF);
                        break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (floatIcon != null) windowManager.removeView(floatIcon);
    }
}
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:text="@string/start" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/btnStart"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/btnStart"
        android:layout_below="@id/btnStart"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/stop" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This should help you get started, unless you have already finished after all of this time.

Comment: You should not use a link as an answer. You should include all relevant information in yours and use the link as an attribution/reference. Also, if you have a difficulty with your own project you should ask a new question. Refer to this one if it helps give background.

Comment: I have revised my answer to include the code i used and ref'ed the links.